# Unable to start Office SharePoint Server Search on index server in moss 2007

Tags: 2007, search

I am unable to start Office SharePoint Server Search for index server.
Steps i followed:
1.I browsed cental admin site->oprations->servers in farm
2.selected Index server fri=om servers list
3.clicked start option in from of "Office SharePoint Search Service"
After this got below:

```
***An unhandled exception occurred in the user interface.Exception Information: Client found response content type of 'text/html', but expected 'text/xml'. 
The request failed with the error message: 
-- 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/> 
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;} 
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} 
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF; 
background-color:#555555;} 
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} 
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} 
--> 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"><fieldset> 
<h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2> 
<h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3> 
</fieldset></div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>***
```

Answer (score 1):

Before attempting anything else make sure your service account for the Farm and Search service have not an expired password!

Comment: All Service accounts are valid.They are not expiring.